# Simple seo-friendly custom $_GET url rewrite with htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this url:

```
http://sitename.com/?game=runescape
```

Is it possible to modify the htaccess file or rewrite the url via Wordpress to become like this:

```
http://sitename.com/game/runescape
```

Comment: what is `game`?

Comment: Is `game` a post type or taxonomy? Have you enabled pretty permalinks in the admin area?

Answer (score 1):

First, add a WordPress page named `game` to direct requests to.

Next, add the `game` query var so WordPress knows what it is:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa_query_vars' );
function wpa_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'game';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Then, add a rewrite rule to handle the incoming requests and direct them to your page:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_add_game_rule' );  
function wpa_add_game_rule() {   
    add_rewrite_rule(  
        'game/([^/]+)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=game&game=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );   
}
```

Last, create a template named `page-game.php` and add `get_query_var( 'game' )` to see the requested game.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to "Settings"=>"Permalinks" and check the option "Post Name".

WordPress handles the rest for you. If `game` is a custom post type, you do not need to do anything else.

EDIT:
As you mentioned that `game` is a script outside WordPress, this question is out of scope for this community.

Comment: Unfortunately I've created a custom database 'game', where the data for each game is stored. Via $_GET['game'], I can request a custom page template and via the slug, create an instance of 'game' to display custom game data.

Comment: So what do you do with WordPress?

Comment: I like the login form and the plugins :D.